# Continuity of the restriction of a function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $n\geq1$, and $F$ a closed subset of $ \Omega$. Suppose $f$ is a real-valued function on $ \Omega$, and set 
$$A=\lbrace x\in F: f(x)=0\rbrace.$$
If the restriction of $f$ to $A$ is continuous, can we conclude that $A$ is closed in $F$? 
My answer is yes! Am I right? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Yes indeed $A$ is closed if the restriction of $g=f|_A$ is continuous

We have that $A=g^{-1}(\{0\})$ and $\{0\}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Because of the continuity of $g$ we have that $A$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Thus $A$ is closed in $F$ with respect to the subspace topology because $A=F \cap A$

Comment: But why $A$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Comment: @M.Rahmat.. because the inverse image of a closed set under a continuous function is a closed set.I t is a theorem in topology.

Comment: This is wrong. That argument only proves that $A$ is a closed subset of $A$, which is a trivial assertion. Actually, the statement that you are trying to prove is fals. The set $A$ can be anything.