# Continuity of the restriction of a function 2

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am steel confused about this question  ([Continuity of the restriction of a function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2369712)). Let $F$ be a compact of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $f$ a real valued function defined on a neighborhood of $F$, and set $$A=\{x\in F: f(x)=0\}.$$ Suppose the restriction of $f$ to $A$ is continuous.

1) Can we conclude that $A$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

2) Can we conclude that $A$ is closed in $F$?

I cannot write down the details of these conclusions. Any help is welcome. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The restriction of $f$ to $A$ is **always** continuous: it's a constant function by definition! So you have no restriction on $f$ at all. So the question becomes: let $A$ be an arbitrary subset of $F$. Is $A$ closed?

Answer (score 2):

No, we cannot conclude that A is closed in $\mathbb R^n$. Suppose that $A$ is *any* subset of $F$ and consider the function$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb R^n&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x\in A\\1&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$Then $A=\{x\in F\mid f(x)=0\}$. And the restriction of $f$ to $A$ is continuous, since that restriction is constant. But $A$ can be any subset of $F$, closed or not.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=1$ and $F =[-1,2]$. If $f(x)=0$ for $0<x<1$ and $1$ for all other $x$ then $A$ is not closed in $\mathbb R$ even though the restriction of $f$ to $A$ is continuous.

A subset of $F$ is closed in $\mathbb R$  iff it is closed in $F$ so the answer for the second part is the same.